# How to add external css file in wufoo

Tags: wordpress, integration, wufoo

I have an one doubt about wufoo for. After making wufoo form, how to customize, I want to import css file to my form. Can anybody know how to import css file ,who are familiar in wufoo form?

Answer (score 0):

-click the "Themes"
-select "Advanced"
-paste the link. make sure where you hosted the css it has https.

Answer (score 0):

You can make css file on your server and give path of that file in "Advanced" option in wufoo login. and change option ssl as false in wordpress